# Show CheckBox-Border on IsChecked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following xaml-code to set a border on a checkbox if the checkbox is checked.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Lime"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <CheckBox Content="Use Method 1" />
    <CheckBox Content="Use Method 2" />
    <CheckBox Content="Use Method 3" />
</StackPanel>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. If I check a CheckBox, nothing happens to the border.

What is wrong with this xaml-code?

Comment: I tried this code and all work fine, border are set as expected.

Comment: I just realized, that the border is drawn around the small box but I want it around the box and the Text in the CheckBox-Content

Comment: Are you setting the `BorderBrush` or `BorderThickness` properties on the `<CheckBox>` tag itself in your production code? That's the only reason I can think of why your trigger wouldn't work, because properties set on the tag will take precedence over any styled values. See MSDN's page about [Dependency Property Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need a custom check box template. See below the Aero default style with the modifications that you need:

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBoxFillNormal" Color="#F4F4F4"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBoxStroke" Color="#8E8F8F"/>
    <Style x:Key="EmptyCheckBoxFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="CheckRadioFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxFillNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxStroke}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource EmptyCheckBoxFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                            <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:BulletChrome BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"/>
                        </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </BulletDecorator>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="ContentBorder" Value="Lime"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource CheckRadioFocusVisual}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

You can add a setter to change border brush of `BulletChrome` when check box is checked (add a name for bullet chrome and duplicate the setter in trigger for `IsChecked`, just change the name in the new setter)

### EDIT:

Oh, and you'd need this xmlns definition:

```
xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
```

(of course you'd need a reference to `PresentationFramework.Aero` assembly)